# sdb: Disk read/write request responses are too high (read > 20 ms for 15m or write > 20 ms for 15m)

Tags: linux, performance, hard-drive, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I use Zabbix agent to monitor my Linux servers.
I start to receive this alarm:
sdb: Disk read/write request responses are too high (read > 20 ms for 15m or write > 20 ms for 15m)

incident expression:
{server03:vfs.dev.read.await[sdb].min(15m)} > 20 or {server03:vfs.dev.write.await[sdb].min(15m)} > 20

How can I troubleshoot this alarm and check which process is stuck my disk?

Comment: What kind of disk is it? Do you have *heavy* disk workloads? What's the smart data for the disk showing?